# Get user input for one minute, aggregating score

Tags: javascript, html, timer, while-loop

I'm new to javascript and html, which you can probably tell by my code. I am building a simple login game that will help kids practice logging onto devices at school. I want it to run for 1 minute while the game keeps score.

What I really need is a while loop that tests to see if a minute has passed, and during the minute, aggregates the score, resetting the user input fields each time. Coming from a C++ background, I'm really confusing myself going back and fourth between html and java. Specifically, I need that timer in java, and I need a while loop in game_login_entered that runs for a minute (or, I need said while loop in another java function, where it calls game_login_entered() repeatedly for 1 minute.

Thank you for taking the time to read this messy post. I hope I've been specific enough. Can anyone help me sort this out?

```js
function credentials() {
  var real_username = document.getElementById('real_username_field').value;
  var un = document.getElementById('real_username');

  var real_password = document.getElementById('real_password_field').value;
  var pw = document.getElementById('real_password');

  var teacher_confirmation = confirm("Check with your teacher. Is this correct?\nUsername: " + real_username + "\nPassword: " + real_password);
  if (teacher_confirmation == true) {
    //START GAME

    //clear old stuff
    $('.removeMe').hide();
    //start timer (statically set at 60 seconds)
    onTimer();
    //show the hidden game time form.
    $('.gametime').show();

  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function game_login_entered() {

  var real_password = document.getElementById('real_password_field').value;
  var real_username = document.getElementById('real_username_field').value;
  var pw = document.getElementById('game_password_field').value;
  var un = document.getElementById('game_username_field').value;
  var score = 0;
  var multiplier = 1;
  document.getElementById("game_password_field").style.borderColor = "gray";
  document.getElementById("game_username_field").style.borderColor = "gray";
  var x = 0;


  if (pw == real_password && un == real_username) {
    document.getElementById("user_feedback1").innerHTML = "CORRECT!";
    document.getElementById("user_feedback2").innerHTML = "";
    score = score + (100 * multiplier);
    multiplier = multiplier + 1;
  } else if (pw != real_password && un != real_username) {
    document.getElementById("game_username_field").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("user_feedback1").innerHTML = "\nIncorrect username.\nEnter: " + real_username;
    document.getElementById("game_password_field").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("user_feedback2").innerHTML = "\nIncorrect password.\nEnter: " + real_password;
    multiplier = 1;

  } else if (pw != real_password) {
    document.getElementById("user_feedback1").innerHTML = "\nIncorrect password.\nEnter: " + real_password;
    document.getElementById("game_username_field").style.borderColor = "gray";
    document.getElementById("game_password_field").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("user_feedback2").innerHTML = "";
    multiplier = 1;

  } else if (un != real_username) {
    document.getElementById("user_feedback1").innerHTML = "\nIncorrect username.\nEnter: " + real_username;
    document.getElementById("game_username_field").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("game_password_field").style.borderColor = "gray";
    document.getElementById("user_feedback2").innerHTML = "";
    multiplier = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("user_feedback_score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
  document.getElementById("user_feedback_multiplier").innerHTML = "Multiplier: " + multiplier;

}
```

```css
Body {
  font-family: Calibri;
  background-color: #3399FF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
body input,
body button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
form > div {
  margin: 1em;
}
form button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
/*
Blinker 
I'm not sure how this works, but hopefully it will allow me to blink the timer */

<style type="text/css"> .blink_text {
  -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: blinker;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: blinker;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: red;
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title" style="blink_text" align="center">Loginator!</h1>
<fieldset class=r emoveMe>
  <legend>First, enter your BCPS One username and password:</legend>
  <label>Username:
    <input type="text" class=r emoveMe id="real_username_field" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Password:
    <input type="text" class=r emoveMe id="real_password_field" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" class=r emoveMe id="mySubmit" value="Submit" onclick="credentials()" class=r emoveMe/>
</fieldset>

<br />
<p1 class=r emoveMe><var id="real_username" class=r emoveMe></p1>
<br />
<p1 class = removeMe><var id="real_password" class = removeMe></p1>
<br />

<label class = gametime>Username:<input id="game_username_field" class = gametime></label>
<br />
<label class = gametime>Password: <input id="game_password_field" class = gametime></label>
<br />
    
    
<!-- While loop/timer should start here-->
<button id = "button_game_start" onclick="game_login_entered()" class = gametime>log in</button>
<br />
<p3 id = user_feedback1 class = gametime></p3>
<br />
<p3 id = user_feedback2 class = gametime></p3>    
<br />
<p3 id = user_feedback_score class = gametime></p3>
<br />
<p3 id = user_feedback_multiplier class = gametime></p3>

<!--This jquery code should make the enter key work when the focus is in the password feild, but it doesn't...-->
<script>
    $(#game_password_field).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $(#button_game_start).click();
    }
});
</script>

<!--This hides the game form. We will show it in credentials() when the game starts.  -->
<script>
     $('.gametime').hide();
</script>
    
    
<p id="demo"></p>

  
<!--This button starts the timer. The function is called in credentials(). I would like to put this in the java section so we could customize the timer.-->    
<!-- <button onclick="onTimer()">Play!</button> -->

<div id="mycounter" class = gametime></div>  

<script>    
i = 60; 
function onTimer() {

 document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = "Time left: " + i;
  i--;
  if (i < 0) {
    alert("Time's up!");
    $('.gametime').hide();
    return;
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/powstatan/534d3ucd/159/

Comment: You should consider changing the questions's tags to remove `Java` and add `Javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to aggregate every minute, use the `setInterval` function.

```
var score = 0;
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

setInterval(function() {
    score++;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       inputs[i].value = "";
    }

},60000);
```

Here's the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b65902mm/1/

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I saw this solution before when researching the problem, but could not get it to work in my code. Would document.querySelectorAll return all inputs that the user entered during that minute? As of right now, my code works, but only 1 time, and I just need to get it to keep going back and getting more inputs while the timer counts down.

Comment: One thing I noticed that may help: as I enter more usernames and passwords, it is still checking if they are correct, and setting the score, but I think it's resetting the score at 0 every time. If the score variable existed outside of this function, the whole thing might work.

Comment: I fixed it. It should have been `setInterval`. Also the score variable doesn't get reset. Check the fiddle

Comment: Thanks again, Richard!